# Swift Alamofire: How to validate both a valid request and a valid response code

Tags: ios, swift, rest, validation, alamofire

We have this Alamofire error handling:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, getUrl("mystuff")).responseData { response in
    guard response.result.error == nil else {
       //Handle error
    }
 }
```

It works well if the server cannot be reached or the certificate is invalid, etc.

But if the server can be reached but returns a 404/etc response code this error handling code doesn't get triggered.  How can you fold support for this use case into this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to read the docs.....    I ended up using the Alamofire `validate` [API method](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#validation):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, getUrl("mystuff")).validate().responseData { response in
    guard response.result.error == nil else {
       //Handle error
    }
 }
```

This handles the validation on the return code as well as general connection issues.  Also handles validation on the content type (see the linked doc for more info...)

Answer (score 1):

The result property of response contains the code if it is not nil.
Else, you can get the statusCode.

```
if let error = response.result.error 
{
  let statusCode = error.code
} 
else 
{ 
  let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
}
```

Comment: This works thanks.  But I found that the Alamofire API has a nice method to automatically do this so I went with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have valid both request, response and result to be get and its working for me, my code is given below

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: nil)
                .responseJSON { (request, response, result) -> Void in

                    print(result.value)

                    if(result.isSuccess) {
                        completionBlock( error : nil, responseDict : result.value as! [String : AnyObject])
                    }
                    else {
                        print("error")
    //                    completionBlock(error: errno_t, responseDict: nil)
                    }

            }
```

hope its helpful

Comment: When I run this code `isSuccess` is true even when a 404 is returned.  It returns false if the server is down.  But I want to handle both cases (return false for both).

Answer (score 0):

Use

`public func validate(_ validation: @escaping Validation) -> Self` from `DataRequest`